# Possible to configure log4j with 2 ConsoleAppenders, each with differrent layout?

Tags: log4j

I'd like to have 2 different log4j ConsoleAppenders defined with different layouts.  I tried the following:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.stdoutMDC=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdoutMDC.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdoutMDC.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdoutMDC.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L (hibernateLoadPlanWalkPath->%X{hibernateLoadPlanWalkPath}) - %m%n
```

However, when I attempt to use these appenders I am running into problems.  I have the first appender attached to root and then attempt to attach the second to certain ancestor loggers:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout

log4g.logger.org.hibernate.loader.plan=trace, stdoutMDC
log4g.additivity.org.hibernate.loader.plan=false

log4g.logger.org.hibernate.persister.walking=trace, stdoutMDC
log4g.additivity.org.hibernate.persister.walking=false
```

The trouble I am having is that the messages from both of those ancestor loggers end up going to the stdout appender *and not* the stdoutMDC appender.  I tried both with and without disabling additivity, but no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Lol, helps if you use the right prefixes.  'log4j.logger' instead of 'log4g.logger' :)

Answer (score 0):

please try this.

It may help out you

Note : %X{userName} - this is how you fetch data from Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC)

## note the %X{userName} - this is how you fetch data from Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC)

log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern = %-4r [%t] %5p %c %x - %m - %X{userName}%n

log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, consoleAppender

Comment: Thats not at all what I am asking.  The MDC value is only pertinent to a certain set of  logging categories.  In fact, if I move the same exact pattern layout to the appender attached to root it works fine.